# Sticky footer in table of react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm basically looking to do this with react-virtualized Table:
https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/?component=ScrollSync#/components/Table

make sticky footer, like header, with scrollable table body.

I created 2 tables in AutoSizer, for header+body and footer. But I have incorrect footer width when first table has scroll: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO3DN.png). How can I fix it? Or implement sticky footer by another way

```
  <AutoSizer>
{({ height, width }) => {
    const tableColumns = this.getColumns(columns, width);

    return (
        <div>
            <Table
                width={width}
                height={Math.min(height, HEADER_ROW_HEIGHT + BODY_ROW_HEIGHT * dataLength)}
                rowHeight={bodyRowHeight}
                onScroll={onScroll}
                rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                rowCount={dataLength}
                rowGetter={({ index }) => data[index]}>
                {tableColumns}
            </Table>
            {total && <Table
                width={width}
                height={40}
                gridClassName={'has-footer'}
                disableHeader
                rowHeight={bodyRowHeight}
                rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                rowCount={1}
                rowGetter={() => total}>
                {tableColumns}
            </Table> }
        </div>
    );
}}
```

*UPDATE*

*render method*

```
<AutoSizer>
{({ height, width }) => {
    const tableColumns = this.getColumns(columns, width);

    console.log('tableRef:', this.tableRef && this.tableRef.state);
    return (
        <div>
            <Table
                width={width}
                height={Math.min(height, HEADER_ROW_HEIGHT + BODY_ROW_HEIGHT * dataLength)}
                ref={this._setRef}
                headerClassName={headerClassName}
                headerHeight={headerRowHeight}
                rowHeight={bodyRowHeight}
                rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                rowCount={dataLength}
                rowGetter={({ index }) => data[index]}>
                {tableColumns}
            </Table>
            {total &&
            <FooterComponent
                rowData={total}
                width={width - (this.tableRef && this.tableRef.state.scrollbarWidth || 0)}>
                {tableColumns}
            </FooterComponent>}
        </div>
    );
}}
```

```
_setRef = (ref) => {
        this.tableRef = ref;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

2 thoughts:

1) Using a whole new `Table` for your sticky footer is overkill. It would be more efficient to just render a header (either by importing `defaultTableHeaderRowRenderer` or by just rendering your own divs).

2) Your width is off on the footer by the amount of the scrollbar. It's a little hacky, but you could get the measured with from `Table` via a ref (eg `tableRef.state.scrollbarWidth`) and then just [do what `Table` does](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/2462beacc7c1c405004f18dbde2e8ed3db597d05/source/Table/Table.js#L343) and set that amount of `padding-right` on your footer CSS.

Comment: Very useful! I wrote own divs with styles from column. How can I get fresh `scrollBarWidth`? I set `ref` as component variable, then try to set width as `width - this.table.statescrollbarWidth`. But sometimes when scroll exists I get 0 as `scrollbarWidth`. Sometimes is correct `17` after reload page. `componentDidUpdate` doesn't help. Give me more your thoughts, please.

Comment: You can use the same helper function I use if you'd like (`dom-helpers/util/scrollbarSize`). Or you could tap into an event from `Table` (eg set an `onRowsRendererd` callback and check for a new scrollbar size).

Comment: anyway `onRowsRendered` may call _before_ `_setScrollbarWidth`. I couldn't find out on what does it depends.